# How to take out the padding of the CupertinoPicker?

Tags: flutter, flutter-cupertino, cupertinopicker

I have two CupertinoPicker and a i need to take out the gap that it has between then,anyone have an idea please ? [image]

```
 Center(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
                height: 200,
                width: 100,
                child: CupertinoPicker(
                    itemExtent: 20,
                    onSelectedItemChanged: (index) => setState(() {
                          this.index == index;
                        }),
                    children: definingHoursList())),
            SizedBox(
                height: 200,
                width: 100,
                child: CupertinoPicker(
                    itemExtent: 20,
                    onSelectedItemChanged: (index) => setState(() {
                          this.index == index;
                        }),
                    children: definingHoursList()))
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation for the CupertinoPickerDefaultSelectionOverlay](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoPickerDefaultSelectionOverlay-class.html) class.

By passing it to CupertinoPicker you can disable the margin, but it'll also lose the rounded corners.

```dart
  CupertinoPicker(
    selectionOverlay: const CupertinoPickerDefaultSelectionOverlay(
      capStartEdge: false,
      capEndEdge: false, 
    ),
    // other parameters,
  )
```